# Running Mocha and Istanbul on multiple cwd

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, istanbul

I'm looking for a way to manage testing and getting the coverage of a project that has multiple microservices, which have their own tests in their directories.

```
└── services
    ├── service-1
    │   ├── src
    │   └── test
    ├── service-2
    │   ├── src
    │   └── test
    └── service-3
        ├── src
        └── test
```

Each service has its own tests, they all need to be executed from their own cwd in order to make the requires and paths working.

**What would be the best way to launch those tests from the root of the project and getting nyc to get the coverage of the whole project ?**

As of right now, I'm using a bash script `test.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set +e

(cd ./services/service-1 && npm run test)
(cd ./services/service-2 && npm run test)
(cd ./services/service-3 && npm run test)
```

And launching it with `npx nyc ./test.sh`, but if a test fail on `service-1`, `service-2` and `service-3` will still be executed and considered successful despite the first service failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you executes the tests a single chain of commands, you script exit code will map the first failed test (or the last successfull one if no tests fails)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./services/service-1 && npm run test \ 
  && cd ../service-2 && npm run test \ 
  && cd ../service-3 && npm run test
```